# Getting all likes on User's all posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

this is my models.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug=AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    body=models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posted_subjects')
    created=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    points=models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              related_name='liked_subjects',
                              blank=True)
```

How can I get all points of the subjects posted by a particular user? I mean if a User "Mark" has posted 30 subjects, how can I get the sum of all points of those 30 subjects?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
data = Subject.filter(author__username='Mark').aggregate(points_count=Count('points'))
points_count = data['points_count']
```